# Here is No.183 sql questions from Leetcode. There is one answer that do really fast but I am confused

Tags: sql, mysql

Questions: There are two tables: Customers and Orders. Write a solution to find all customers who never order anything.

Here is the answer:
SELECT name as customers FROM customers
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE customerId = customers.id) < 1

My question is how does that work using the where clause above

Comment: If there isn't a record in the `orders` table for a given `customer_id`, it means they haven't ordered anything. This solution is using the result of a subquery to determine that. What part of the solution are you confused about? There's some oddities, like `customerId` (typically `customer_id` or `CustomerId`; I've never seen pascal case in a database table), and `COUNT(*) < 1` is odd; can simply do `COUNT(*) = 0` instead, since `< 1` literally only allows for `0` (since `COUNT()` can't return negative numbers, etc.)

Comment: The observations above are relevant - but keep in mind that training can deliberately introduce stuff - for learning - and not necessarily to show the best performing solution. But using `< 1` instead of `= 0` is a bit weird.

Comment: *Here is the answer* FORMALLY this solution is not correct. Nothing prevents the existence of the order where there is no any product (or its amount is equal to zero).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name AS customers
FROM customers
WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM orders
        WHERE customerId = customers.id -- the "correlation" is here
        ) < 1
```

The given answer (*which isn't necessarily the best possible solution*) is using a "correlated subquery". This "correlation" takes place through the where clause of the subquery and it enables the subquery to "align" the subquery result (i.e. the `count(*)` value) to each row of the customers table, then that value is compared to `<1`.

Characteristics of a "correlated subquery"

- Nested queries: The SQL statement has a query within a query. The "inner query" (everything inside the parentheses) is nested within the "outer query".
- Reference to the "outer query": The "inner query" is referencing `customers.id` which comes from the "outer query". This is the key characteristic of a correlated subquery.
- Row-by-row execution: Correlated subqueries run once for each row processed by the outer query. In this case, for each customer, the database is counting the number of orders that customer has
- Performance: Correlated subqueries can be slower than other types of queries because they require multiple executions of the inner query

There are at least 2 other approaches for such a problem:

- using NOT EXISTS (also known as a "left semi-join"), or
- using a LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause (sometimes known as "left excluding join")

```
    -- using NOT EXISTS
    SELECT name AS customers
    FROM customers
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM orders
            WHERE customerId = customers.id -- "semi-join" formed by this
            ) 
    ;
    
    -- using LEFT JOIN
    SELECT name AS customers
    FROM customers
    LEFT JOIN ORDERS ON orders.customerId = customers.id
    WHERE orders.customerId IS NULL
```